# Is there an appropriate sequence to tests during model diagnosis?

Tags: time-series

How should one order (sequence) the following tests?

1. Stationarity test
2. Johansen cointegration test
3. Normality/Histogram test
4. Autocorrelation test
5. Heteroskedasticity test
6. Multicollinearity test

Or, does the sequence not matter?

Comment: I would say that the beauty of econometrics is that it is NO cookbook.